# Angular trigger function after login

Tags: angular, typescript, service, authentication, routes

I have an Angular application in which I want to fire a function after successful login.

Authentication service is very simple.

It looks like this:

```
@Injectable()
export class AuthenticationService {
  isLoginSubject = new BehaviorSubject<boolean>(this.hasToken());

  constructor(
    private http: HttpClient
  ) { }

  login(username: string, password: string) {
    localStorage.setItem('user', username);
    return this.http.post(PROD_URL, {username: username, password: password})
      .map(response => {
        if (response && response['token']) {
          localStorage.setItem('userToken', 'Token ' +  response['token']);
          this.isLoginSubject.next(true);
        }
        console.log(response);
        return response;
      });
  }

  logout() {
    localStorage.removeItem('userToken');
    this.isLoginSubject.next(false);
  }

  isLoggedIn() {
    return this.isLoginSubject.asObservable();
  }

  private hasToken(): boolean {
    return !!localStorage.getItem('userToken');
  }

}
```

I have only a login dialog with username and password, and after successful login I want to fire an event.

The function looks like this:

```
getEvents() {
    this.rest
     .getEvents()
     .subscribe(
       data => {
         this.store.dispatch(new AddEventsAction(data));
       },
       (err: HttpErrorResponse) => {
         console.log(err.status);
       },
       () => console.log('Done')
     );
   }
```

Now my problem is the following:

When I login in, my screen gets shown, but my events are not there. If I use F5, or browser to refresh the page, then the events appear.

How can I get the events, and show them without needing to reload the page?

Comment: I see you are using ngrx, you should check out [@ngrx/effects](https://github.com/ngrx/platform/blob/master/docs/effects/README.md)

Comment: @JoshuaChan Awesome man, thank you for the tip.